# use a constructor as a method parameter

Tags: java, methods, arraylist, parameters, constructor

I'm writing a class that will build a SQL table create statement. what I'd like to do is call a method something like `createTable(String tableName ColAndTypes... ct )`.  When I write the method I don't get any compile errors. I'm having trouble passing the values into the method when I call it though and I think it's because my syntax is wrong and I'm not sure how to fix it. I was wondering if you could look at the example I have provided and let me know what I need to do to fix it. Thanks so much for your help!

```
import java.util.*;
public class foo
{
public class bar{
    public String sBar1, sBar2;
    public bar(){
        sBar1 = "null";
        sBar2 = "null";
    }
    public bar(String sBar1, String sBar2){
    this.sBar1 = sBar1;
    this.sBar2 = sBar2;
    }
}

String sFoo;
List<bar> bi;

public foo(){
    sFoo = "null";
    bi = new bar();
}
public foo(Strinf sFoo, bar bi){
    this.sFoo = sFoo;
    this.bi = bi;
}

public void runFooBar(String sFoo, bar... barArgs)
{
    this.sFoo = sFoo;
    for(bar x:barArgs){System.out.Println(bi.get(x).sBar1   + ":" + bi.get(x).sBar2);}
}

public static void main(String[] args)  
{
    foo fi = new foo();
    fi.runFooBar("foo 1", ("1 sBar1","1 sBar2"),("2 sBar1 ","2 sBar2"))

}//end main

}//end class
```

Comment: `bi` is a `List` but you're initializing it as a `bar`. You have a typo `Strinf` instead of `String`. `List#get(int)` expects an `int`, but you are passing it a `bar`.

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions. Classes should be in `PascalCase`, so `Bar` rather than `bar`. To answer your specific question, you don't. We'll not unless you are using Java 8. To solve your current problem pass in _instances_ of your (renamed) `Bar` class.

Comment: I see I do have some typos, thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, but this fixes your syntax errors.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Foo {
    public static class Bar {
        public String sBar1, sBar2;

        public Bar(String sBar1, String sBar2) {
            this.sBar1 = sBar1;
            this.sBar2 = sBar2;
        }
    }

    String sFoo;
    List<Bar> bi;

    public Foo() {
        bi = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public Foo(String sFoo, List<Bar> bi) {
        this.sFoo = sFoo;
        this.bi = bi;
    }

    public final void runFooBar(String sFoo, Bar... barArgs) {
        this.sFoo = sFoo;
        for (Bar x : barArgs) {
            System.out.println(x.sBar1 + ":" + x.sBar2);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo fi = new Foo();
        fi.runFooBar("foo 1", new Bar("1 sBar1", "1 sBar2"), new Bar("2 sBar1", "2 sBar2"));

    }//end main
}//end class
```

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help. Looking at your corrections I can see where I made my mistakes!

Comment: I'm glad I could help you out.